# Android DarkMode : Value night not working

Tags: android, android-theme, android-darkmode

I am developing Day/Night feature in my app so I read those documents and start developing it.

It's working fine with default value in Day or Night
with deligate method `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(*)`.

For customize **night** theme color I create **values-night** folder and inside I create **colors.xml** file like below.

```
res -> values -> colors.xml
res -> values-night -> colors.xml
```

After I place that color but not applying in Night theme! Its very strange why value-night colors is not applying always its showing default night color?
I have researched some but can't find the solution.

**Note**: Recreate activity is resolved my issue but I don't want to recreate

Here is my build.gradle file

[image]

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60038517/11158194 this link may be helpful for you.

Comment: can you please post your app build.gradle file?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try below dark mode code which I am use.

**Step - 1**

First of create **night** folder into your resource file like below image(i.e. values-night)

[image: Create night mode folder]

**Step - 2**

Create **styles,strings and colors** xml file for **night mode** same as below image and add your night mode color,string and style which you want to show in your app when night mode was apply.

[image: Create night mode xml files]

For better user experience add **window Animation** in your style.

**values --> style.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBarAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Add this theme where you change mode -->
    <style name="NoActionBarWithChangeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- This will set the fade in animation on your change theme activity by default -->
    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**values-night --> style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. values-night.xml -->
<style name="NoActionBarAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Add this theme where you change mode -->
<style name="NoActionBarWithChangeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
</style>

<!-- This will set the fade in animation on your change activity by default -->
<style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

**fade_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" >
    </alpha>
</set>
```

**Step - 3**

Add this below code in your **splash screen** if you want to **set night mode as per device mode** first time when application installed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!CommonUtils.isToogleEnabled(SplashActivity.this)) {
        if (CommonUtils.isDarkMode(SplashActivity.this)) {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this, true);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this, false);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    } else {
        if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this)) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    //your code
}
```

**Step - 4**

Add this below code in your all activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    //your code
}
```

**Step - 5**

**Change mode** using below code

```
private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

binding.imgNightMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(MainActivity.this);
        CommonUtils.setIsToogleEnabled(MainActivity.this, true);
        if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this, false);
            mActivity.get().recreate();
        } else {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this, true);
            mActivity.get().recreate();
        }
    }
});
```

Below methods are **CommonUtils**.

```
private static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT_MODE";
private static final String TOOGLE = "TOOGLE";

public static boolean isNightModeEnabled(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPrefs.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, false);
}

public static void setIsNightModeEnabled(Context context, boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, isNightModeEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

public static void setIsToogleEnabled(Context context, boolean isToogleEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(TOOGLE, isToogleEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isToogleEnabled(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPrefs.getBoolean(TOOGLE, false);
}

public static boolean isDarkMode(Activity activity) {
    return (activity.getResources().getConfiguration()
            .uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: If i am not want to recreate then? Did you have any solution for that

Comment: @MohitSuthar So,you need to start again same activity because without recreate you don't see any changes

Comment: Check WhatsApp and other application it does not recreate i guess If you are not going with custom theme it's fine

Comment: And I was trying all solution this is best if you are use other option of recreate or again start same activity it's take large time and it is not more user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not looking for this

Comment: @MohitSuthar What you want?

Comment: Without recreate you can not change them https://stackoverflow.com/a/25483738/11158194

Comment: @MohitSuthar But I am found one solution to add WindowAnimationTransition for best view see my style.xml into updated answer.

Comment: This does NOT answer the question of why `values-night\colors.xml` is not being used when night mode is active.

Comment: You're not answering the question why the night mode values are not being applied, you are only pasting code

Answer (score 3):

Change appcompat dependency from **1.1.0** to **1.0.0**, There is some issue to update resource in 1.1.0. This trick worked for me.

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'//Remove 
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0' // Add
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: I will try and let u know

Comment: Have you used app theme like this ? <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">

Comment: Yes, but I am using MaterialComponent.DayNight theme

Comment: Lifesaver! this solved an issue with setDefaultNightMode causing a res id not found exception